# How To Hide A Drive In The Navigation Tree When Mounting To Your Home Folder

Tags: mount, hard-drive, home-directory, fstab, autohide

When I mount my "VM" drive to my *home folder* it shows in the folder tree and an eject button appears next to it.

[image]

When I mount my "VM" drive to my *root folder* it doesn't show in the folder tree and there is no ejection button.

[image]

Why does Ubuntu have this behavior? It only makes sense for removable media and other drives that mount to the media folder to behave like this. It doesn't make sense for drives mounted to the home folder.

I'd prefer to mount the drive to my home folder for ease of accessibility and I don't want to be able to accidentally eject it. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I submitted a bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-gnome/+bug/1501547

The best work around was to create a simlink from the folder in your root directory to your home folder. The following instructions are helpful for making simlinks: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84175/create-a-symbolic-link-relative-to-the-current-directory

Answer (score 0):

How do you mount? There are different ways to do that.

One way it should stop it to show up is to use the /etc/fstab file to specify mountpoints.

Why this behavior? It can usually be assumed that if you mount run-time via mount or an auto-mount that this device is ejectable. That's why the eject-button shows up. If you mount into non-home though, you need root permissions, the same applies to ejecting it. As you do not run the filemanager as root, the button won't show up.

Comment: I used fstab in the examples above. Like it shows, it still shows in the navigation tree when mounting to the home folder.

Comment: @guttermonk Hm, that is unexpected.  What's the specific fstab line? In the options (fourth) field try `rw,defaults`

Comment: Here's what I used in my fstab: `/dev/sdb1     /VM     ext4     auto,defaults,user     0     0`

Comment: Using `rw,defaults` is redundant. defaults = rw, suid, dev, exec, auto, nouser, and async according to [https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab)

Comment: @guttermonk Yep, didnt read carefully. `auto` is in defaults though too. I'd remove `user` as it says: "Allows a user to mount" but when it's mounted on bootup, it may not be necessary. And maybe because it then gets mounted by `user` it shows up. -- And ofc. I forgot to mention the easy way out: Just mount it somewhere under / but then just symlink from your home to the directory.

Comment: @guttermonk This would make root the owner of the mountpoint so you shouldn't be able to eject it. I'm not sure though whether one can mount under `/home/user/*` without specifying `user` but it should be possible

Comment: You're right, the `auto` was redundant since it's in `defaults`. I got rid of it and tried fstab with and without `user`. The eject button came up both ways.

Comment: @guttermonk That's definitely weird. Without `user` it should only allow the 'mounter' to unmount again - in this case the system. Can you provide this please: `lsblk --output NAME,MAJ:MIN,RM,SIZE,RO,TYPE,MOUNTPOINT,OWNER,MODE,HOTPLUG,GROUP`

Comment: my lsblk didn't have HOTPLUG as an option, but here's the result for the rest:
 sdb      8:16   0 931.5G  0 disk            root  brw-rw---- disk
└─sdb1   8:17   0 931.5G  0 part /VM        root  brw-rw---- disk
sdc      8:32   0 596.2G  0 disk            root  brw-rw---- disk
├─sdc1   8:33   0 566.9G  0 part /Storage   root  brw-rw---- disk
└─sdc2   8:34   0  29.3G  0 part [SWAP]     root  brw-rw---- disk

Comment: @guttermonk I'm completely at loss: The partition is owned by root, the correct modes are set... . The last guess would be the HOTPLUG but as your lsblk doesn't have it (i have no idea why not) we can't check that so easily. == I'm wondering whether you can actually unmount the disk if it's mounted not using `user`. The eject button is there - but what happens if you click it? == My last guesses: It's really set to hotplug or sth. like fuse interferes and still mounts it as user. But at least my workaround with the symlink helped ;-)

Comment: When I mount the drive to my home directory without `user` and try to unmount, it prompts me "Authentication Required" `Authentication is required to unmount /dev/sdb1 mounted by another user`. After I enter it, it says "Unable to unmount 1.0 TB Volume". `Error unmounting /dev/sdb1: Command-line  'unmount "/dev/sdb1" exited with non-zero exit status 1: unmount: /home/linux/VM: not mounted.`

Comment: @guttermonk Then I highly suspect it's a bug indeed. Maybe it's related to https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=586644 -- The bug is that they look up 'who mounted' it and not who *owns* it (eg. `sudo mount` mounts as user but owner is root). == Skimming through the links it might be a udisks issue at the root. So I guess the symlink way is the best :/

Comment: Thanks for all the help and for the symlink idea. At least we got to the root of the problem :)